# Error Obtaining Lock (org.neo4j.kernal.StoreLockException)

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, neo4j

When trying to create new nodes in an already existing database, I am getting the following exception:

`org.neo4j.kernal.StoreLockException`.

The code snippit below is the actual line that results in 
the exception. Below that I have attached some more detail and the full stack trace.

If I create a new folder and use that as the `DB_PATH`, then my code works fine on the first run. On the second run, it will fail with the same exception. It appears something is preventing the lock from being obtained.

I tried to set permissions to Read/Write on every file in the `DB_PATH`. No luck. Is there a setting in one of the config files that must be disabled with regard to locks?

**Code Throwing Exception**

```
graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );
```

**More Detail (Line 6)**

```
private static GraphDatabaseService graphDB = null;
public static final String DB_PATH = "/Users/NtroduceMe/Downloads/neo4j-community-2.0.0-M03/data/ntroduceme";
private static Index<Node> userNodeIndex;
private static Index<Node> rememberMeNodeIndex;
static {
    graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );
    registerShutdownHook(graphDB);
    userNodeIndex = graphDB.index().forNodes("profile_id");
    rememberMeNodeIndex = graphDB.index().forNodes("profile_id");
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Jun 19, 2013 12:12:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ProfileController] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Could not create lock file
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:85)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:296)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:197)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
    at com.NtroduceMe.Utilities.GraphDBManager.<clinit>(GraphDBManager.java:22)
    at com.NtroduceMe.UserProfile.Profiles.createProfile(Profiles.java:141)
    at com.NtroduceMe.UserProfile.ProfileController.doPost(ProfileController.java:61)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**Helper Class I use to Store the Database Instance**

```
public class GraphDBManager {
    public static final String DB_PATH = "/Users/NtroduceMe/Downloads/neo4j-community-2.0.0-M03/data/ntroduceme";
    private static final GraphDatabaseService graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );    
    private static Index<Node> userNodeIndex;
    private static Index<Node> rememberMeNodeIndex;
    static {
        registerShutdownHook(graphDB);
        userNodeIndex = graphDB.index().forNodes("profile_id");
        rememberMeNodeIndex = graphDB.index().forNodes("profile_id");
    }

    public static GraphDatabaseService getGraphDB(){
        return graphDB;
    }

    public static Index<Node> getUserNodeIndex(){
        return userNodeIndex;
    }

    public static Index<Node> getRemberMeNodeIndex(){
        return rememberMeNodeIndex;
    }

    private static void registerShutdownHook(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
    {
        // Registers a shutdown hook for the Neo4j instance so that it
        // shuts down nicely when the VM exits (even if you "Ctrl-C" the
        // running application).
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        } );
    }   

}
```

Comment: Hi bro, have u solved the issue? I'm facing the same problem now.

Comment: A while back I switched to the Bolt API and have not had this issue. I believe I installed neo using sudo using the latest version and not a single installation issue.

Comment: Also, I dont use embedded anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't properly shutting down your database when the program is ending, so it's leaving the lock file there.

You might consider setting up a shutdown hook as described here:
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html#tutorials-java-embedded-setup-startstop

Comment: I have a shutdown hook call in there already. I tried restarting with the shutdownhook removed and I get the same error. I don't think it has anything to do with the ShutdownHook. That's not suppose to get called unless my entire application is closing correct? I'm not suppose to start and stop the database between requests am I? The way I have it setup is that my web application starts the db once when all classes are initialized then registers the shutdown hooks so that it closes the db if the VM exits. Am I suppose to shutdown after every transaction?

Comment: Hmm, no--I suppose this isn't the problem, then.

Answer (score 1):

I just wonder why you shutdown the DB before creating the nodes ?

You can't create nodes using a closed DB, so it can be like that:

```
 graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );
 userNodeIndex = graphDB.index().forNodes("profile_id");
 rememberMeNodeIndex = graphDB.index().forNodes("profile_id");
 Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
 try
    {
    Node node = graphDb.createNode();
    node.setProperty( USER_ID, "userID");
    nodeIndex.add( node, USER_ID, "userID" );
    }
```

and after you fininsh creating all nodes, you can call:

```
   registerShutdownHook(graphDB);
```

Comment: I thought the purpose of the registerShutdownHook function was to act like a callback that only gets called when the VM exits? So calling it actually shutsdown the db?

Comment: Of course it shutdown the DB, it's code is like this 

`private static void registerShutdownHook( final  GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
{
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            graphDb.shutdown();
        }
    } );
}`

As you see, it will simply shutdown the running DB..

Comment: I see. Poorly named function. The term "register" through me off. I'll try this out.

Comment: So it turns out that registerShutdownHook does NOT shutdown the database. Only when the VM closes. The line Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook adds the function to list then never gets called. It's not an immediate shutdown. After removing the all shutdownhook calls and restarting my computer I still get the same error. I don't think it has anything to do with that function.

Comment: you can easily try the code in my answer, it will correctly build the nodes you want, and after finishing the build process `registerShutdownHook(graphDB)` will shutdown the DB. If you need the code for starting the DB correctly after shutting it down, I can give you sample..

Comment: I think your misinterpreting how registerShutdownHook() works. http://technoracle.blogspot.com/2012/05/neo4j-tutorial-4-registering-shutdown.html

Comment: I think that didn't differ of what I said before, but I think also that you can't shutdown the DB and after that create a node.. how can it be?? You firstly create the nodes then shutdown it, that's simply what I know and what really works so fine for me.

Comment: You must be running your java code from a console application then. I should have mentioned my code runs inside a web page in a web server. The JVM never exits. If your running yours from a console the JVM exits as soon as your request is finished. It does not work that way in Java EE. Thanks for your help anyway. If you don't understand what I'm talking about then look at the answer to this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920763/java-neo4j-rest-and-memory

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what happened, but could you simply check if there's a "store_lock" file in your graphdb directory and if not, just create it (with "touch" command) or something? That should solve it.

Comment: Yea there is a store_lock file

Comment: I added some more code but basically I carry the db instance around in the static block of a helper class. The error gets thrown immediately at the point of creating the database. I'm using Mac OSX mountain lion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you still search for a solution or not but while working on a project I stumbled upon the same problem. It happens if the database is not closed correctly after the program terminates or if you have registered a shutdownhook it occurs after the process is somehow forcibly terminated (by some..... very.... considerate... college for example) so the hook never gets called. That means you will have to release the lock during the next startup of the program. So here my code for doing this, hope it still helps someone somehow.

```
StoreLocker lock = new StoreLocker(new DefaultFileSystemAbstraction());
        lock.checkLock(new File(DB_Location));
        try {
            lock.release();
            graph = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_Location);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Of course you should only call this if something during DB opening went wrong! And that should be clear but i'll say it either way just to be sure. The same error occurs if there are two or more instances of your program, using this way of releasing the lock in this case will trigger further problems!

Answer (score 1):

In the Neo4j manual :

> The EmbeddedGraphDatabase instance can be shared among multiple
>   threads. Note however that you can’t create multiple instances
>   pointing to the same database.

And I had this error simply because I ran Neo4j Server before deploying the application. As soon as I run the Neo4j server, an empty "lock" file is created and placed in the database directory.

So I suppose it is because an instance was already created, and I tried to create a **new instance** by my Java Application, which is **impossible**.