# Failed in opening neo4j DB

Tags: java, tomcat, neo4j

Hi i'm deploying an app that i wrote on a machine (all deployment with tomcat).
when running the application (in browser) i get the error 
 taken out from catalina.out :

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory,
> ```
>
> /home/ubu01/neo4jDB
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:143)
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:43)
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
>         at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:129)
>         at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:117)
>         at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:185)
>         at com.saeedh.utils.NeoQuery.InitDatabase(NeoQuery.java:46)
>         at com.saeedh.utils.NeoQuery.AuthinUser(NeoQuery.java:153)
>         at com.saeedh.servlets.start.Login.doGet(Login.java:79)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at com.saeedh.filters.PageValidationFilter.doFilter(PageValidationFilter.java:48)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@4724a951' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
>   cause exception.
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:462)
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:112)
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
>         at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:139)

but the application works fine on my machine .
i tried the solution suggested here :
[Error Obtaining Lock (org.neo4j.kernal.StoreLockException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183228/error-obtaining-lock-org-neo4j-kernal-storelockexception)

it didn't work , i am accessing the DB using :

```
db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(new File("path to the database")).loadPropertiesFromFile("path to properties file")
        .newGraphDatabase();
registerShutdownHook(db);
```

what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one process at a time can access the store directory on disk.

As you start an embedded database, make sure that all servers and other processes accessing that same database are stopped cleanly.

Comment: how do i know which processes are using the database ?

Comment: thanks neo4j-service was running and it was using the database .